# Git: How to list all matched files at a given commit with a single command?

Tags: git

How can I find all files matching a particular regex pattern that exist at a given commit? I know that I can pipe the output of ls-tree to grep, ie:

`git ls-tree -r --name-only --full-tree <sha> | grep <pattern>`

or I could checkout the commit and use ls-files:
`git checkout <sha>
git ls-files <pattern>`

But a single git command that doesn't alter the state of the repository would be ideal; my project has several other git commands, and preferably, they would be consistent.

Comment: I'd use grep. You say you want regular expression matching, and pathspecs generally do glob-style matching instead; and despite the documentation, the `<paths>` arguments to `git ls-tree` are not patterns, at least as tested in Git `2\.1[01]` (regexp) / `2.1[01]*` (glob).

Comment: What is wrong with `git ls-tree ... | grep ...`?